# kendo ui using slider with a template

Tags: kendo-ui, slider

I'm using a slider inside of Kendo UI Template.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template3">   
  <div>
       <b> Grades: </b>  <br />  
       <input id="slider" class="temperature" value="#= temper #"  data-bind="value:temper"/>
  </div>    
</script>
```

The template is called by edit function on the grid.

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({                        
    editable: {
        mode:"popup",
        template:kendo.template($("#template3").html())
    },
...
```

I created the JS slider

```
var slider = $("#slider").kendoSlider({
                    increaseButtonTitle: "Right",
                    decreaseButtonTitle: "Left",
                    min: 0,
                    max: 5,
                    smallStep: 1,
                    largeStep: 2
                }).data("kendoSlider");
```

The problem is that the Slider is not displayed on the popup editor. Only is displayed the value. Could anybody please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your slider element isn't initially available thus $("#slider") returns nothing. You should call this code once the grid initializes its editor template. Use the edit event of the grid for that:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({                        
    editable: {
        mode:"popup",
        template:kendo.template($("#template3").html())
    },
    edit: function() {
       $("#slider").kendoSlider({
                    increaseButtonTitle: "Right",
                    decreaseButtonTitle: "Left",
                    min: 0,
                    max: 5,
                    smallStep: 1,
                    largeStep: 2
                })
    }
```

Alternatively you can set the data-role attribute:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template3">   
  <div>
       <b> Grades: </b>  <br />  
       <input data-role="slider" 
              data-min="0" 
              data-max="0" 
              data-small-step="1" 
              data-large-step="2" 
              class="temperature" 
              data-bind="value:temper"
       />
  </div>    
</script>
```